# Chromebase Kiosk App - Invalid Application

Tags: google-chrome-app, kiosk, google-chrome-os, chromebox

I am attempting to create a kiosk app for an Acer Chromebase that I have.  I know the Chromebase is setup to accept and run a kiosk app successfully as I used a publically available kiosk app to test and the Chromebase ran it.  So that part of it I know is good.

I have created a kiosk app by researching all available documentation and posts I could find, and I do have `"kiosk_enabled":true` in the manifest.json file.  I have copied this app over to the Chromebase, loaded as an Unpacked app, and it ran successfully within a window.  I have then taken that app and published in the Chrome store, setting the visibility to Unlisted and not Private.  I can then go to Chromebase, put the link into the browser and it finds it in the store, and I can install it and run it, and it will run successfully within a browser window.

Now for the problem.  When I go to "Manage Kiosk Applications" and put the ID of my app in there, it comes back with a completely useless "Invalid Application" error.  It would be nice if it told WHAT was invalid about it, but it doesnt.  It doesnt matter if I use the App Id, or the store url link to the app, I still get Invalid Application.  Like I said earlier, I did get an app Id to another kiosk app I found out there and when I put that Id in there it accepts it and installs it, so I know it can be done, but mine is failing.

I have used the App Builder to create this kiosk app.

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name": "DIDI Kiosk",
    "version": "1.4",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "37.0.0.0",
    "permissions": [
        "webview",
        "power",
        "storage",
        "videoCapture",
        "geolocation",
        "pointerLock",
        "system.display",
        {
            "fileSystem": [
                "write",
                "retainEntries",
                "directory"
            ]
        },
        "accessibilityFeatures.read",
        "accessibilityFeatures.modify"
    ],
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": [
                "js\/foam.js",
                "js\/cab.js",
                "config.js",
                "background_main.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    "kiosk_enabled": true,
    "default_locale": "en",
    "icons": {
        "128": "img\/128.png"
    }
}
```

And here is my config.js file:

```
window.config = {
   "model_": "AppConfig",
   "id": 1,
   "appName": "DIDI Kiosk",
   "version": "1.4",
   "homepage": "https://v1.didi.dansmill.com:8080",
   "enableNavBttns": false,
   "enableHomeBttn": false,
   "enableReloadBttn": false,
   "enableLogoutBttn": false,
   "kioskEnabled": true
};
```

Does anyone have any idea just what the criteria is in the "Manager Kiosk Applications" are to validate an app?

}Dan

Comment: Having the same issue. App will install unpacked and works fine. Works fine as a regular install via webstore.  Try to add the published/unlisted app id as a kiosk app and it says `invalid application id`.

Answer (score 0):

I think It would be a nice idea to try to install as kiosk app the app that google provides as example:

See "*Or, create a Chrome kiosk app with navigation controls:*" here: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3316168

If you succeed, then It means your app is missing something. Perhaps on the manifest?

If not, then perhaps there is something missing on the procedure itself. Here (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/jztb4P_CE0c) a guy had the same problem and he finally could install the app with these extra steps

> I create a account in the chrome web store.
>
> I upload my test app and publish my test app.
>
> And then I install my test app in chrome web store.
>
> After these, I can start my test app on kiosk mode.

But I believe you already did that...

Anyways, I think the first thing to know if you are able to install the sample app as a kiosk app.